# Reference: authoritative reference on Gibbs and Boltzmann's entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, entropy

Can someone reference a good, standard textbook on thermodynamics or quantum mechanics that explicitly states the formula for Gibbs and Boltzmann's entropy (or maybe Shannon as well)?

I am asking because I have seen many papers where authors use these terms interrchangably and sometimes will even say Gibbs-Boltzmann entropy so I have became very confused.

Comment: Wrong place to ask... we recently had a post here that ended up with most people confusing these concepts, too. :-) Having said that, what's wrong with the Wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann%27s_entropy_formula. As for Shannon... that's got nothing to do with physics proper, but you will find a lot of folks who don't grok why it's different.

Comment: [Cédric Villani](http://cedricvillani.org/for-mathematicians/) has a very useful and physically intuitive book on entropy/irreversibility.  That's about as fundamental as you will probably get...

Comment: I'm not sure if I can post this as an answer since it is by no means authoritative, but a few years ago I gave a seminar (as a student) on exactly this topic: the different notions of entropy, in particular defining and explaining Boltzmann, Gibbs and Shannon entropy, and their differences. I just uploaded my seminar notes: http://microcanonical.com/notes_entropy_seminar.pdf I hope it's useful! I know how frustrating the literature can be on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

### Gibbs vs Boltzmann entropies

The question was discussed by Jaynes in  [Gibbs vs Boltzmann entropies. American Journal of Physics, 33(5):391–398, 1965](http://link.aip.org/link/?AJP/33/391/1) (also availableble from [here](https://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/node1.html) as Ref 21).

One must be careful by what we mean "Boltzmann entropy" because Boltzmann tried a lot of different things and came across various different aspects of entropy.

**Boltzmann entropies**

- Perhaps the most well known Boltzmann entropy is the equation
  $$
  \tag{1}
     S = k \log W
  $$
  which is inscribed on his tomb. Today we understand this to represent the entropy of an isolated system with fixed energy, volume, and number of particles.
- Boltzmann also came up with the expression
  $$
  \tag{2}
     S = -k \sum_i p_i \log p_i
  $$
  by discretizing the phase space of particles.
- Boltzmann obtained yet another entropy via his $H$ theorem:
  $$
  \tag{3}
     S = - \int f(v) \log f(v) dv
  $$
  where $f(v)$ is the velocity distribution of a single particle in a dilute gas. As Jaynes shows, this entropy converges to the Gibbs entropy in the ideal-gas limit.

**Gibbs entropy** Gibbs wrote the following equation for the entropy:
$$
\tag{4}
\boxed{
   S = - k\int \rho(\Gamma) \log \rho(\Gamma) d\Gamma
}
$$
where $\Gamma = (\mathbf r_1,\cdots;\mathbf q_1,\cdots)$ is the vector of positions and momenta of all particles and $\rho(\Gamma) d\Gamma$ is the $N$-particle probability, namely, the probability to find the microstate of the entire system in the the region $(\Gamma,\Gamma+d\Gamma)$ of phase space. This is the entropy of statistical mechanics.

**Shannon entropy** Shannon obtained the entropy of generic probability distribution $p_i$ as
$$
\tag{5}
   S = - \sum_i p_i \log p_i
$$

---

**Relationship between the various entropies**

- Gibbs's entropy is Shannon's entropy in the continuous domain applied to the *equilibrium distribution of microstates*.
- Boltzmann's entropy in Eq 1 is obtained from Gibbs entropy when all microstates are equally probable (the case in an isolated system, i.e., a microcanonical ensemble).
- Boltzmann's Eq 2 is analogous to the Gibbs/Shannon entropy.
- Boltzmann's entropy in Eq 3 represents thermodynamic entropy only in the ideal-gas limit (no inter-molecular forces, i.e., no correlation between states of particles).